# errSecInternalComponent when using codesign from within a daemon

Tags: macos, mac, keychain, code-signing, daemons

I have my own running daemon application that listens to a network port and executes some different commands based on the coming request. All is working fine except when trying to execute the following `codesign` command.

`sudo codesign --force --timestamp --options=runtime --entitlements <Entitlements File Path> --sign <Application Certificate Id> <file to sign>`

Where I see an error saying `errSecInternalComponent`. However, when I take the same command and paste it into the terminal it works.

I have my application certificate installed under both `login` and `System` keychains and set to be `Always Trust` in settings.

I tried adding `--keychain` option to specify the keychain path for the `codesign` command.
Also, I made sure that both `login` and `System` keychains are unlocked during command execution.
Besides, I tried adding the following key/value pair to my daemon `plist` file and restarting it.

```
<key>SessionCreate</key>
<true/>
```

All of the above trials failed to fix the issue, I'm out of ideas and any help would be highly appreciated.